# How to set expiry time for image, js & css without using htaccess

Tags: http, caching, http-headers, pagespeed

I just checked "PageSpeed Insights" on my website and realized that i have a problem with some files (such as image/js/css) about their expiry time.

My server is linux, i know it worked with htacces but i'm afraid that the administrator does not enable the mod_expires...

Anyway I pretty sure that there is another way to do this and to declare for a expiry time for image/script/css.

Answer (score -1):

How about using mod_headers (still requires .htaccess):

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|js|css)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=3600"
</FilesMatch>
```

For example.

Comment: No, it requires mod_headers, these are different modules (See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html). Does your provider not have mod_headers installed? That is quite surprising!

Comment: you right, mb...
anyway I'm afraid that also mod_headers is not installed :/

Comment: What's your web host anyway? haven't you considered a VPS where you have full control of available modules :)